# Two Homes In Navigation Menu

Tags: menus, navigation

I have the following listed in my navigation menu:

- Home
- Contact
- Home

When I go to the `Pages => All Pages`, I see

- Home
- Contact

Yet, when I go to the `Appearances => Menus => Pages => View All` I see:

- Home
- Contact
- Home

I've looked for how I can remove the redundant `Home` navigation option in this `Appearances` menu, but I don't see that option.  Also, there is no second home page from the pages.  So how can I remove this from the navigation, or prevent this from appearing twice?

What I've tried

- I tried removing the home page completely and it did remove one of the homes from the navigation, but I had no way to edit the home page then.
- In looking through the customization, I haven't been able to discover a way to control which pages appear in the navigation menu - for an example, if I wanted to have a test page that I was working on, it would appear even if I didn't want it.  I've looked all over the `Appearance => Customize` option.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the same problem I had, Wordpress added a home option to the menu without it being added in the appearance menu items so I could not remove it. I googled for ages and found two solutions. Neither of them worked but if I combined the two they did. Open the functions.php file in your site files. If you are using a common theme there might be a function already in there that states something like `$args['show_home'] = true;` if that is the case then just change the true to false and save the file.

If you are using your own theme or the current theme does not add home to menus by default then just copy the below code, paste it in functions.php, change the yourTheme to the name of your theme and save

`function yourTheme_page_menu_args( $args ) {
    $args['show_home'] = true;
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_page_menu_args', 'yourTheme_page_menu_args' );`

Answer (score -1):

- First you need to click on ***My Site*** in the top left corner.
- Then click on ***menus*** (Found under "***Personalize***")
- From there you should see a list of the items that are displayed in your navigation bar. Delete any duplicates and you should be good to go.

My noobish 2 cents

Comment: Sorry, I don't see any `My Site` in the top left corner.  Even CTRL-F doesn't find it.  You can post a screenshot of where you're getting this, but I think that you (1) either skipped a stet and are in some page you forgot to specify, or (2) using some other development blog than Wordpress.

Thanks.